# Colored Button Shadow

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to add a colored shadow to a *Button* (Custom renderer?) in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: What did you find when you searched for _button shadow color Xamarin forms_ in your preferred search engine?

Comment: Nothing, only for Xamarin.Android and not for Xamarin Cross Platform

Comment: Similar to border ?Do you have any effect pictures?